# ‘Authentication object cannot be null’ error when query method is performed in open endpoint

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-data-neo4j

I have public method `checkProfileToken` in `AuthenticationController` that grabs some information from the Neo4j database using the Neo4jRepository implementation - `ProfileRepository`.

I’ve ignored Spring Security for this request `/check_profiletoken` in `OAuth2SecurityConfiguration` class:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    // …

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) {
        webSecurity.ignoring().antMatchers("/check_profiletoken"); // ingoring WebSecurity for this entry

    }

    // …
}
```

**Controller (AuthenticationController.java):**

```java
@RestController
public class AuthenticationController {
    @Autowired
    ProfileRepository profileRepository;

    // …

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/check_profiletoken")
    public ResponseEntity<?> checkProfileToken(@RequestBody final JSONObject jsonRequest) {
        // HTTP response container
        HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        responseHeaders.setLocation(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().buildAndExpand().toUri());

        final String token = (String) jsonRequest.get("token");
        Integer tokenType = null;

        try {
            tokenType = (Integer) jsonRequest.get("tokentype");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new ActionResponseDTO(
                            new ActionResponseItemDTO(ActionResponseTypes.ERROR, ActionResponseCodes.INVALID_DATA,
                                    ActionResponseDomains.PROFILE_TOKEN, null, "Token type is invalid!")),
                    null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        
        ActionResponseDTO actionResponses = commonService.checkProfileToken(token,
                ProfileTokenType.getByCode(tokenType));

        if (actionResponses.isValid()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(actionResponses, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(actionResponses, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }


    // …
}
```

In method `checkProfileToken` I call `getProfileForActivation` query method of the `ProfileRepository`

**Repository (ProfileRepository.java):**

```java
@Repository
public interface ProfileRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Profile, String> {
    // …
    @Query("MATCH (p:Profile)-[r:HAS_PARENT]->(g:Group) WHERE p.uuid=$profileId RETURN g.displayName as companyName, p.honorificPrefix as honorificPrefix, p.givenName as givenName, p.familyName as familyName, p.gender as gender")
    ProfileActivation getProfileForActivation(@Param("profileId") String profileId);
    // …

}
```

Here is an error that I got when performing query above:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.<init>(SecurityExpressionRoot.java:60)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension$1.<init>(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.data.repository.query.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$EvaluationContextExtensionAdapter.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:369)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.lambda$toAdapters$2(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:159)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.toAdapters(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:160)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.access$000(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider$ExtensionAwarePropertyAccessor.<init>(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:182)
    at org.springframework.data.spel.ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareEvaluationContextProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.getEvaluationContext(ExtensionAwareQueryMethodEvaluationContextProvider.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.SpelEvaluator.evaluate(SpelEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.spel.ParameterizedQuery.resolveParameter(ParameterizedQuery.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.getQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.execute(AbstractGraphRepositoryQuery.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.getProfileForActivation(Unknown Source)
    at com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.CommonServiceImpl.checkProfileToken(CommonServiceImpl.java:116)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:367)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.checkProfileToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.infotemp.spring.controller.AuthenticationController.checkProfileToken(AuthenticationController.java:1276)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Please, I will be very grateful if you can help to solve this problem. I'm new to Spring Security and Spring Data Neo4j.

---

### UPDATES:

**Method `checkProfileToken`:**

```java
@Service("commonService")
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class CommonServiceImpl implements CommonService {
    /* ... */
    
    @Override
    public ActionResponseDTO checkProfileToken(String token, ProfileTokenType tokenType) {
        if (tokenType == null) {
            LOG.error("Invalid token type on sign up! Received token type: " + tokenType);
            return new ActionResponseDTO(
                    new ActionResponseItemDTO(ActionResponseTypes.ERROR, ActionResponseCodes.INVALID_DATA, ActionResponseDomains.PROFILE_TOKEN, null, "Token type is invalid!"));
        }

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(token)) {
            return new ActionResponseDTO(
                    new ActionResponseItemDTO(ActionResponseTypes.ERROR, ActionResponseCodes.INVALID_DATA, ActionResponseDomains.PROFILE_TOKEN, null, "Token is required!"));
        }

        final ProfileToken activationToken = profileTokenRepository.checkToken(token.substring(0, 32), tokenType);

        // if token found
        if (activationToken != null) {
            // if USER_REGISTRATION found
            if (ProfileTokenType.USER_REGISTRATION.equals(tokenType)) {
                ProfileActivation profileActivation = profileRepository.getProfileForActivation(activationToken.getProfileId());

                return new ActionResponseDTO(new ActionResponseItemDTO(ActionResponseTypes.SUCCESS, ActionResponseCodes.SUCCESS, ActionResponseDomains.PROFILE_TOKEN, profileActivation, ""));
            } else {
                return new ActionResponseDTO(new ActionResponseItemDTO(ActionResponseTypes.SUCCESS, ActionResponseCodes.SUCCESS, ActionResponseDomains.PROFILE_TOKEN, activationToken, null));
            }
        } else {
            return new ActionResponseDTO(
                    new ActionResponseItemDTO(ActionResponseTypes.ERROR, ActionResponseCodes.INVALID_DATA, ActionResponseDomains.PROFILE_TOKEN, null, "Token is invalid!"));
        }
    }
    
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Show `com.infotemp.neo4j.service.impl.CommonServiceImpl.checkProfileToken`. It is the problem.

Comment: @dur, I added this to the initial description

Comment: here is 116th row mentioned in the error stack:
`ProfileActivation profileActivation = profileRepository.getProfileForActivation(activationToken.getProfileId());`

Comment: Did you anotate  `getProfileForActivation`?

Comment: @dur, What do you mean with "annotate"? I've only `@Query` annotation for that query as you can see in my description. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see it. For some reason your annotation checks security. That means you cannt ignore the URL, becaus this method needs it.

Comment: @dur, So, because `@Query` annotation for some reasons does security check I cannot use this query method within ignored URL, right?
But it's interesting in that case, because before dependency upgrades it worked fine (`spring-data-neo4j` was updated from 5.0.1.RELEASE to 5.3.4.RELEASE version). 
I can't unignore that URL, because it used for not logged in users.